# Passing an 8-bit alpha-only texture to GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, alpha

how does one pass an 8-bit alpha-only texture to GLSL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say what OpenGL version you're working with. But really, since you're using GLSL, you shouldn't *care* whether the 8-bits-per-pixel data is in the *alpha* component or not. What you care is that your texture data has only one channel, it's 8-bits-per-pixel, and that it is accessible by a known component.

GL 3.x+ provides the `GL_R8` [image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format). Before that, you could just use `GL_INTENSITY8` (which was removed from core OpenGL 3.1). The difference is that `GL_R8` only puts the single channel into the red component, so GB will be 0 and A will be 1. The intensity format broadcasts the single channel into all four components, so the RGBA will each be the same value.

Your shader doesn't need to be changed. Just get the red component of the sampled value.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, if I don't change the shader code, and still get the 3 (RGB) components. Does this mean the shader processing time is about 3 times of only doing calculation on 1 channel.